# Swift: How to declare function signature that takes mutable / var parameter?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

Simple question, so hopefully there is a simple answer.  How do you capture / define a function type that takes a var parameter?

```
func foo(a:Int) -> Int  {
    return a + 1
}

func bar(var a:Int) -> Int  {
    return ++a
}


// define function type taking a constant parameter like foo above
typealias Foo = (Int)->Int

// try to a function type taking a var parameter like bar above
typealias Bar = (var Int)->Int
    // gives a misleading compiler error about needing a leading semi colon
```

Does this seem like a compiler bug or am I missing something obvious?  I am using Xcode 6.1.1.

Comment: It should be noted that the use of var is to be deprecated in Swift 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect of `var` on a parameter is internal to the function's implementation. Because it has no effect on the caller of a function, it's not part of the function's signature / type.

Hence, your function `bar` is of the same type as the function `foo`, aka the type you've aliased as `Foo`.

---

Note that your function `bar` doesn't modify the value it was passed:

```
var num = 1
bar(num)    // -> 2
num         // -> 1
```

If that's what you were looking for, what you actually want is an `inout` parameter. That *does* modify the function semantics, so it *is* part of the function signature:

```
func baz(inout a: Int) -> Int {
    return a++
}
typealias Baz = (inout Int)->Int
let b: Baz = baz
var num = 1
b(&num)     // -> 1 (return from before the post-increment)
num         // -> 2
```

Comment: Right! It felt like I was missing something simple, and it was - `var` vs `inout`.  Strange that it would give an error though - should be agnostic per your comment.  Evidently, what I really had wanted was: `typealias Bar = (inout Int)->Int`, and this works.

Comment: Just saw your edit now, and you correctly deduced my intent.  Still strange that it gave the missing leading semi-colon error, but evidently there the compiler team is working on better error reporting.  Thanks.

Comment: Compiler errors could definitely be better in general ([filing bugs about that helps](http://bugreport.apple.com)). But there's probably a limit to how much better — if you throw keywords in places they aren't expected, the compiler has to guess at your intent. They probably can't diagnose *all* the possible ways to write illegal code.